# How to download a file from a server with express

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node.js and express. I want to create a file on the server and then download when the end point is hit.
Here is the code I currently have.

```
router.get('/download', (req, res) => {
 const fileController = new FileController();
  fileController.generateJSONFile()
  .then((file) => {
     fs.writeFile('fooFile.json', file, 'utf8');
  }).then((success) => {
    res.download('fooFile.json');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    res.status(500).send();
 });
});
```

I would also like it to immediately delete the file off the server after the download is completed.

I do not need to use res.download() if there is a better way to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 3):

Would this help? This should tell the browser to download the file as `fooFile.json`. This would not require saving of temporary file.

```
router.get('/download', (req, res) => {
 const fileController = new FileController();
  fileController.generateJSONFile()
  .then((file) => {
     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');
     res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="fooFile.json"');
     res.send(file);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    res.status(500).send();
 });
});
```

if you just want to send `json`.

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
res.send(file);
```